# Calculation of a Fourier Coefficient.

Tags: fourier-series, physics

I need some help calculating this Fourier coefficient.

Periodic signal, six-steps. Odd periodic signal.

[image]

I've made the calculations myself, not using any software, and the results are these:

$$I_{\text{rms}}=\sqrt{2}\times I$$

and the fundamental is $b_1=1.909$.

Isn't that weird - the fundamental value being bigger than the $I_{\text{rms}}$?

If you can calculate and help me out, I'll be appreciative.

Comment: Since this is not a Q&A electrical engineering site, I advise you to define explicitly in the question the relevant concepts for this application such as "total harmonic distortion" and the "power factor" because they might not be  known by someone which is familiar with the  Fourier series but not with the specific electrical engineering terminology.

Comment: This is probably more suited to the EE stack exchange site, but they might have a similar opinion, mutatis mutandis.

Comment: English correction: (...) a Q&A site for electrical engineering professionals, students, and enthusiasts,  I advise  (...)

Comment: Ok guys, sorry about that and thanks for your help. 

My question should've just stayed between the boundaries of pure math and not about EE stuff. Next time I'll be more careful.

Answer (score 1):

We have $I_\text{rms}^2 = {1 \over \pi}{ \pi \over 3}(I^2+4 I^2 + I^2) = 2 I^2$.

As an aside, with a pure sine wave, we have $I_\text{rms} = {1 \over \sqrt{2}} I_\max$, and here we have $I_\max = 2I$, which would correspond to $I_\text{rms} = \sqrt{2} I$ and a fundamental of $2I$, so these results show
that the fundamental above is consistent with this.

The $\sin$/$\cos$ Fourier series are convenient here, since $i$ is odd,
we need only compute the $\sin$ part, which gives
$\hat{I_k} = {1 \over \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi \sin(kt) i(t) dt  =  2I {1 \over k \pi} (1-\cos(k\pi)+\cos(k{\pi \over 3})-\cos(k {2 \pi \over 3})) $.
Then we have
$i(t) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \hat{I_k} \sin(kt)$.

We have $\hat{I_1} \approx 1.9099 I$.

To compute the THD of $i$, we can use Parseval's theorem which states
$I^2_\text{rms} = {1 \over 2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^\pi i(t)^2 dt = {1 \over 2} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \hat{I_k}^2$, hence
$\text{THD} = {\sqrt{2 I^2_\text{rms} - \hat{I_1}^2} \over \hat{I_1}} \approx 0.31077$.

To compute the power factor, note that since the voltage is a pure sine wave,
the average power is given by $V_\text{rms} {1 \over \sqrt{2}} \hat{I_1}$,
hence
$\text{pf.} =  { V_\text{rms} {1 \over \sqrt{2}} \hat{I_1} \over V_\text{rms} \sqrt{2} I} \approx 0.95495$.

Comment: Yep. That's about the same result I'm getting. But I wasn't really sure about my math here. Thanks for helping me out. 

I was about to say that your THD formula is wrong, but then I noticed you're using peak values in the formula. So it's all right :)

Answer (score 0):

A stepped wave like this can be considered as a sum of several sawtooth waves: $\frac{I}{\pi}\Sigma_k \frac{1}{k}[2\sin(k\theta) + \sin(k(\theta-\frac{\pi}{3})) - \sin(k(\theta-\frac{2\pi}{3})) - 2\sin(k(\theta\pm\pi)) - \sin(k(\theta+\frac{2\pi}{3})) + \sin(k(\theta+\frac{\pi}{3}))] = \frac{I}{\pi}\Sigma_k \frac{\sin(k\theta)}{k}[1+\cos(\frac{k\pi}{3})-\cos(\frac{2k\pi}{3})-\cos(k\pi) ]$

(This may be off by a constant factor, I always get that muddled)

$b_k$ is zero whenever $k$ is a multiple of 2 or 3, otherwise it's $3I/k\pi$, if I haven't blundered.